# Making a colorable image - changing the image's source in code behind messes up events

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a `ColorableImage` custom control, but I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible. The class itself is rather straightforward:

```
public class ColorableImage : Image
{
    private bool ChangedByColor { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UncoloredSourceProperty;

    static ColorableImage()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColorableImage)));
        SourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(SourceChanged)));

        ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(ColorableImage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ColorChanged)));
        UncoloredSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UncoloredSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ColorableImage));
    }


    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource UncoloredSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(UncoloredSourceProperty); }
        protected set { SetValue(UncoloredSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void SourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorableImage cimg = (ColorableImage)d;
        if (!cimg.ChangedByColor)
        {
            cimg.UncoloredSource = cimg.Source;
            if (cimg.Color != null && !cimg.Color.ToString().Equals("#00000000"))
            {
                ColorChanged(d, e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ColorableImage cimg = (ColorableImage)d;

        // This will call the SourceChanged which we don't want (since it will change UncoloredImage)
        cimg.ChangedByColor = true;
        cimg.Source = ColorSource(cimg.Source, cimg.Color);
        cimg.ChangedByColor = false;
    }

    private static ImageSource ColorSource(ImageSource source, Color color)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = (BitmapSource)source;

        if (bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel != 32 && bitmapSource.Format != System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32)
        {
            bitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bitmapSource, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 0);
        }

        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapSource);

        // Get necessary image info to copy into the pixel array
        var bytesPerPixel = (wbmp.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        var stride = wbmp.PixelWidth * bytesPerPixel;
        var arraySize = stride * wbmp.PixelHeight;

        // Copy the image into the pixel array
        var pixelArray = new byte[arraySize];
        wbmp.CopyPixels(pixelArray, stride, 0);

        // Convert the System.Windows.Media.Color to a System.Drawing.Color
        System.Drawing.Color newColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);

        // Put the new pixels into the pixel array
        for (int i = 0; i < pixelArray.Length; i += bytesPerPixel)
        {
            // Only color those pixels that have no transparency
            // This is a very simple alogirthm; you can pretty much only have one color in the image, with the rest of it being completely transparent; it is primarily meant for small, simple icons
            if (pixelArray[i + 3] == 255)
            {
                pixelArray[i] = newColor.B;
                pixelArray[i + 1] = newColor.G;
                pixelArray[i + 2] = newColor.R;
                pixelArray[i + 3] = newColor.A;
            }
        }

        // Remake the image
        wbmp.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, wbmp.PixelWidth, wbmp.PixelHeight), pixelArray, stride, 0);

        return wbmp;
    }
}
```

The coloring algorithm is simple and the idea is to be able to replace every pixel that is not transparent with a given `Color`, which is a dependency property on the control. There is also a read-only property on the control called `UncoloredSource` which will give back the original image source, since the actual `Source` has changed due to coloring.

However, I think what I am doing is breaking some kind of internal binding the `Image` control has on its `Source` property. I am testing this with `ListViewItems` as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <local:ColorableImage x:Name="img" Source="plus-black.png" Color="Red"></local:ColorableImage>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Color" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="minus-black.png" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

...

<ListView>
    <ListViewItem Template="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemControlTemplate1}" />
    <ListViewItem Template="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemControlTemplate1}" />
    <ListViewItem Template="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemControlTemplate1}" />
</ListView>
```

The image changes color successfully, but what I've found is that the `SourceChanged` event never fires again after `Color` is changed. My only guess is this is because I am reassigning the `Source` property in the code-behind in `ColorChanged`, which messes up the trigger... But I am kind of surprised that this would mess it up.

Also, if I switch around the trigger a little bit, this confirms what I think is happening. If I set no initial color, and then in the trigger change the `Source` first and `Color` second, then the source and color change, but when I select a second list item, the previous list item disappears completely, and when I select a third, the second disappears completely, etc., which I think means the trigger can no longer access the old source to revert it (unsure why).

Comment: Seems a little too complicated for just filling icon shapes with some color. Why not just use a Path instead? Then it would even be scalable.

Comment: Or you convert it to a PixelFormat with a color palette, like e.g. `Indexed8`.

Comment: Isn't Path for drawing yourself? I'm trying to color images included in the project

Comment: Myself??? I mean, in a typical WPF application, your icons wouldn't be bitmaps. Instead you usually have Path controls with an icon geometry in their `Data` property.

Comment: Anyways. You problem here seems to be [dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). As soon as you set a local value (which you do in code behind), values from Triggers are ignored. A workaround would be to call `cimg.SetCurrentValue(SourceProperty, ColorSource(...))` instead of `cimg.Source = ColorSource(...)`.

Comment: Or if you really need to have an ImageSource, you might use a [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx) with a GeometryDrawing, with properties `Geometry` for the icon shape and `Brush` for the icon fill.

Comment: Unfortunately `SetCurrentValue` gave me the same problem... I will keep checking out those links though

Comment: I just revisited this today. It works, but only if I give the `ColorableImage` an initial color when it is first created in the XAML. Otherwise, the trigger is unable to revert it (it loses the `Color` somehow I suppose).